# Google app engine: how to get the type of object from a polymodel?

Tags: google-app-engine

Hy,

Model Item
Model Image
Model User

Image and User are extending Item. Item extends polymodel.PolyModel.

Now I have a Model named List. Each Item has a list.
Then I query all the Items for that list and I get an array of Items.
Now I want to loop each object and add a property named 'type' and set it's type(Image|User).

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that. The following should get you the class type for each object:

```
for object in object_list:
    model_name = object.class_name()
```